# How to change the style of an active anchor (in a sidebar nav)?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the style of a sidebar nav anchor when the user scrolls and hovers over the section relevant to that particular anchor (bootstrap scrollspy).
that anchor has 2 classes by default: nav-link and js-scroll-trigger", but when we scroll to a particular section, I see another class added to the anchor : "active".
so How can I change the style of the anchor text (for ex make it dark), using JS ?
I already did this code , but it is not working :

```
const activeNavLink = document.querySelector(".nav-link")
const activeNav = document.querySelector(".active")
experience.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
 if (active)
activeNav.style.color= "black"
}
```

experience is the section wrapping the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add another class and write their color: black; then it will override
the bootstrap class

Comment: thanks man ; this indeed solved my problem !

Answer (score -1):

Check this link [CheckThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active).
You can't access that class name maybe you can style it by CSS. If that hyperlink is active set the color as dark